# swal alert after 10 minutes of inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can I make a swal alert that gets triggered after 10 minutes of inactivity on my laravel app?

Also, there should be a logout button in the swal alert. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

        // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 10) { // ten minute
            alert("enter your html code for logout")
        }
    }
```